# How add more unprotected ranges to sheet with some already unprotected ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet that is protected with some unprotected ranges.

In the first phase as admin I unprotect some ranges with a SCRIPT 1. Unfortunately it takes around 5 min. to execute the script.

User can add a row to the sheet and the script should unprotect some cells in the added row. The problem is that I don't know how to unprotect range when there is already some ranges that are unprotected. At this point when user adds a row script runs a SCRIPT 1 that goes through whole sheet and it takes unfortunately too much time...

SCRIPT 1 - going through whole document (around 5min.)

```
function protect(sheet) {

var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protected sheet');
var arrayRanges = new Array;

for(var i=1;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++){

if(sheet.getRange(i,50).getValue() == "s"){

  range = sheet.getRange(i,3,1,5);
  arrayRanges.push(range);
} else if (sheet.getRange(i,50).getValue() == "d"){
  range = sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6);
  arrayRanges.push(range);
} else if (sheet.getRange(i,50).getValue() == "r"){
  range = sheet.getRange(i,12,1,26);
  arrayRanges.push(range);
}
}
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(arrayRanges);

protection.addEditor("xxx@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}
```

I tried to add new unprotected range with SCRIPT 2, but it works the way that erases results of the SCRIPT 1 and leaves me only with the results of the SCRIPT 2.

SCRIPT 2 - adding new unprotected range

```
function protect(sheet) {

var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protected sheet');
var arrayRanges = new Array;

var range = sheet.getRange(1,3,1,5);
arrayRanges.push(range);

protection.setUnprotectedRanges(arrayRanges);

protection.addEditor("xxx@gmail.com");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}
```

I run the scripts through WebApps.

Comment: Why is line "protection.addEditor("xxx@gmail.com");" is before line "protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());" ? It doesn't make any sense..

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use ".getRange" and ".getValue" in a loop, if it can be avoided by using ".getValues"

Try the following script code:

```
//SCRIPT 1
function protect(sheet) {
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protected sheet');

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var r = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastCol);
  var v = r.getValues();

  var arrayRanges = new Array();

  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++){
    if( v[i][49] === "s" ) {
      //range = sheet.getRange(i,3,1,5);
      arrayRanges.push( 'C'+(i+1)+':G'+(i+1) );
    }
    else if ( v[i][49] === "d") {
      //range = sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6);
      arrayRanges.push( 'B'+(i+1)+':G'+(i+1) );
    }
    else if ( v[i][49] === "r") {
      //range = sheet.getRange(i,12,1,26);
      arrayRanges.push( 'L'+(i+1)+':AK'+(i+1) );
    }
  }
  var ranges = sheet.getRangeList(arrayRanges).getRanges();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(ranges);

  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  protection.addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
};

//SCRIPT 2 - adding new unprotected range
function addUnprotectedRanges(sheet) {  
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect();
  var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3,1,5);
  unprotected.push(range);
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotected);

  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  protection.addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
};
```

Comment: I'm curious would you recommend using `sheet.protect().remove();` at the beginning to answer the adding additional rows part of the question? And then just proceed to reset all of the unProtectedRanges since they will run much faster now that you have suggested using getValues().  I really don't know...I'm asking.

Comment: @Cooper, I forgot to include the solution for SCRIPT 2, thanks! I have updated my answer and added "function addUnprotectedRanges(sheet)"

Comment: Most Welcome! :)